# Vuetify single select data table by row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to get a Vuetify single select data table to be selectable by the row instead of by a checkbox.

The current example I see on Vuetify's documentation is: Ex. 1 https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api. That's generally what I want but I want to remove the checkbox and just select by row.

I saw a previous version was able to accomplish something close with slots: Ex. 2 https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables.

I've attempted a few different approaches to use slots in the 2.1.3 release but I seem to be missing something since I haven't been able to get it to work. I'm current what I want implemented using a button, but I seem to have trouble with getting the row selectable.

```
<v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :single-select="singleSelect"
    item-key="name"
    show-select
    class="elevation-1"
    >
        <template v-slot:item.data-table-select="{ isSelected, select }">
            <v-btn color="green" :value="isSelected = !isSelected" @click="select($event)"></v-btn>
        </template> 
</v-data-table>
```

EDIT: I tried to implement a selectable data table with slots but it doesn't seem like item.selected works? Is this still the correct method to select a row item?

```
<v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :single-select="singleSelect"
    item-key="name"
    show-select
    class="elevation-1"
    >
        <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
            <tbody>           
                <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.name" :active="item.selected" @click="item.selected = !item.selected">
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>CONTENT</td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.fat }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.carbs }}</td>
                    <td>CONTENT</td>
                </tr>
           </tbody> 
      </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make single data select you have to make selected item key stored in another variable like "selectedItem", you should change your code like this:

```
<tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.name" 
  :active="selectedItem == item.name" @click="selectedItem = item.name">
```

PS:

- make sure to use unique key for your items
- selectedItem is a variable in the data object

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your props

```
 single-select="true"
```

in your template u used
`single-select="true"`
and vuetify is looking for data that named true ex.

```
    data () {
        return {
                true:true
               }
          }
```

if you have data name true I there will be no problem
I think the right way to do that is

```
 single-select
```

that means that you set the value for props single-select = true 
you can check documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#data-tables)

Comment: Example 1 is working, since the single-select wasn't a v-bind it wasn't causing issues setting the value directly but I changed to an established data prop with default value "true." The main question is directed at example 2 tho. The `<v-btn>` example works but the `<tr>` example doesn't

Comment: ow sorry my bad I thought it was bind

Comment: This props `single-select` work only on vuetify 2.X.X and versions above only

Answer (score 0):

I tried syntax `:single-select=true` and it worked fine.